# Container port is accessible from the host but not from another container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, containers

I have a docker-compose file that looks like this:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  ci:
    image: "ci_test:latest"
    networks: [mynetwork]

  postgresql:
    image: "postgresql:latest"
    networks: [mynetwork]

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

The image postgresql is created by this dockerfile:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM postgres:15-alpine AS certs_build

COPY scripts/setup_tls.sh /

RUN apk add --update --virtual .build-deps openssl && \
    /setup_tls.sh /TLS && \
    apk del .build-deps && \
    chown -R 0:70 /TLS && \
    chmod 0640 /TLS/server/private/postgres.key /TLS/client/private/client.key

FROM postgres:15-alpine

COPY --from=certs_build /TLS /TLS
RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d && \
    apk add --no-cache lighttpd && \
    echo -e "ssl = on\nssl_cert_file = '/TLS/server/postgres.crt'\nssl_key_file = '/TLS/server/private/postgres.key'\nssl_ca_file = '/TLS/ca/ca.crt'" >> /usr/local/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample

COPY docker/postgresql/create_flask_user.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY docker/postgresql/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
COPY docker/postgresql/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf /etc

EXPOSE 5432 8080
CMD ["postgres"]
```

In the postgresql container, besides the postgresql server, I have a lighttpd server running, configured to listen at port 8080 (started as part of the code executed by docker-entrypoint.sh). After starting the postgresql container I can connect to ports 5432 and 8080 from the host. From the ci container, I can only connect to postgresql:5432, but not to postgresql:8080. DNS is working properly, as the container gets successfully resolved, and in postgresql image I have the directive `EXPOSE 5432 8080`.

How can I get to 8080 from the ci container?

Comment: Do you mean you have a separate lighttpd container; is that the `ci` container?  If you're trying to run an HTTP daemon and PostgreSQL in the same container, how (and why) did you set it up?  It seems like the contents of the Dockerfile(s) are a critical part of a [mcve], can you [edit] the question to include enough details to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I don't see where anything in your container is *listening* on port 8080. You're only starting `postgres`, which listens on port 5432.